# max size_t value on send() in C

Tags: c, sockets, send

I'm writing a tcp server in C but I'm facing problems on send. I read local file and send data back to the client, when the file is small I have no problems, but when it becomes bigger I have this strange situation:

server tcp:

```
 // create socket, bind, listen accept

// read file
fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
// malloc for the sending buffer
ssize_t read = fread(sbuf, 1, file_size, fptr);

while(to_send>0) {
  sent = send(socket, sbuf, buf_size, 0);
  sbuf += sent;
  to_send -= sent;
}
```

On huge files sent becomes equals to the max value of size_t, I think that I have a buffer overflow. How can I prevent this? What is the best practice to read from a file and send it back?

Comment: What type is `sent`? `send` returns a value of type `ssize_t`

Comment: I have ssize_t sent

Comment: You don't seem to check that the return value of `send` is not less than 0. How do you know it was successful?

Comment: I'm building this method step by step, for now I have a printf to check and on small files everything is ok

Comment: It's usually best to read the file in chunks (e.g. 8192 bytes) and send write each chunk back to the socket. That way you don't have to allocate a huge amount of memory to handle this request. Besides, your data will be split up into chunks at the tcp/ip level anyway. So, you gain no advantage by trying to send it all in a single call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you send `buf_size` bytes every time, even if there aren't that many left.

For example, pretend `buf_size` is 8 and you are sending 10 bytes (So initially, `to_send` is also 10). The first `send` sends 8 bytes, so you need to send 2 more. The second time, you also send 8 bytes (Which probably reads out of bounds). Then, `to_send` will be will be -6, which is the same as `SIZE_MAX - 5`.

Simple fix is to send `to_send` if it is smaller:

```
sent = send(socket, sbuf, to_send < buf_size ? to_send : buf_size, 0);
```

Also, `send` returns `-1` if it is unsuccessful. This is the same as `SIZE_MAX` when it is assigned to a `size_t`. You would need some error handling to fix this.

Comment: There is no need for a branch. OP should first to_send to the size of the buffer, and than decrease it by the value by the number of sent bytes, and use it as a size argument to `send` function.

Answer (score 0):

> On huge files sent becomes equals to the max value of size_t, I think
>   that I have a buffer overflow.

Since `sent` gets its value as the return value of `send()`, and `send()` returns `ssize_t`, which is a signed type unlikely to be wider than `size_t`, it is virtually certain that what is actually happening is that `send()` is indicating an error by returning -1.  In that case, it will also be setting `errno` to a value indicative of the error.  It cannot return the maximum value of `size_t` on any system I've ever had my hands on.

> How can I prevent this?

In the first place, before you worry about *preventing* it, you should be sure to *detect* it by

1. declaring `sent` as a `ssize_t` to match the return type of `send()`, not a `size_t`, and
2. checking the value returned into `sent` for such error conditions.

Second, if you are really dealing with files longer than can be represented by a `ssize_t` (much less a `size_t`), then it is a poor idea to load the whole thing into memory before sending any of it.  Instead, load it in (much) smaller blocks, and send the data one such block at a time.  Not only will this tend to have lower perceived latency, but it will also avoid any risk associated with approaching the limits of the data types involved.

Additionally, when you do so, be careful to do it right.  You have done well to wrap your `send()` call in a loop to account for short writes, but as @Artyer describes in his answer, you don't quite get that right because you do not reduce the number of bytes you try to send on the second and subsequent calls.

> What is the
>   best practice to read from a file and send it back?

As above.

Comment: my file size will fit in ssize, I have an errno=32 -> SIGPIPE